# PL manifold (piecewise-linear) that is not DIFF nor triangulable: uniquely triangulated or not?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, piecewise-continuity

We know that a classification of manifolds include:

- (TOP) topological manifolds
- (PDIFF), for piecewise differentiable
- (PL) piecewise-linear manifolds
- (DIFF) the smooth manifolds

[image: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863039/on-manifolds-top-pdiff-diff-pl]

I know that

1) Diff (Differentiable) manifold = smooth manifold

2) Diff manifold is always a triangulable manifold?

> question 1: Is Diff manifold always uniquely triangulated? What do we mean by uniquely triangulated?

3) PL manifold = Diff manifold up to 6 dimensions.

4)  PL manifold in 7 dimensions may be smoothed=differentiable, but not uniquely.

> question 2:  Is PL manifold in 7 dimensions still triangulable? (although some triangulation may not be unique?)
>
> question 3: Thus PL manifold may not be  triangulable, in which dimensions (such as 7 or 8 dimensions, and/or above)?

Comment: For Question 1, check the references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_manifold#Smooth_manifolds).

Comment: Every PL manifold admits a triangulation regardless of dimension.